# LUIS - Entity Type List, How to best use?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a bot that is connecting to LUIS for Intent and Entity recognition.

The end goal of the bot is all around Staff Directory lookups on a SQL server. It currently looks up an Employee by name i.e. Who is Joe Bloggs, (Intent: Who_is_Employee; Entity: Communication.ContactName).

But I want to expand and have available the ability to search people by Sector, Department, and Job Role i.e. Who is in Corporate Medical, Who is in Marketing, Who is a Broker.

I have created a List Entity with the Sectors as Values. I've then created any Synonyms for those Entities, but now I want the capability for Job Role. For example; "Who is a Broker". I see there is a 'Role' section to the entity type, but can't get it to work or detect this entity.(Probably because that's not how it works).

Any ideas?

Intents: 
Who_is_Employee
Who_is_Sector

Entities: 
Communication.ContactName (for Employee by name)
Who_is_Sector (for employees by sector)

Comment: can you give us some samples and let us know what detection that you desire in them?

Answer (score 0):

As seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-roles

Use roles to identify subtypes for pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

Role is definitely not what you want (as per CrazyMerlin).

I think I would approach it by working backwards. To clarify; since you are doing lookups in SQL server, what is it that you need to have to extract that information?

For example, with "Who is in Marketing"; i'm guessing it might turn into something vaguely like `select fullname in users where department='Marketing'`. So, in this case, you need to to know the entity `marketing` and the intent to `find users`.

You might want to have different intents for looking up Sector, Department, Job. Depending on how you need to use that in your SQL queries. You will need to make sure that you give lots of utterances to insure thorough training, as some scenarios might be very similar.